# Python pip3 pocketsphinx installation error

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, pocketsphinx

I am having this problem while installing pocketsphinx in python3

I'm using anaconda3, windows 10 .

**pip install --upgrade pocketsphinx**

Below is the error which I got while installing pocketsphinx.

```
Collecting pocketsphinx
     Using cached pocketsphinx-0.1.3.zip
     Building wheels for collected packages: pocketsphinx
     Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pocketsphinx ... error
     Complete output from command /home/geek/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c                                              
     "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-k634wg4p  
     /pocketsphinx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', 
     open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',    
     '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d  
      /tmp/tmp6ts477xjpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
     running bdist_wheel
     running build_ext
     building 'sphinxbase._ad' extension
      swigging swig/sphinxbase/ad.i to swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c
   swig -python -modern -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include  
    /sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig-   
     outdir sphinxbase -o swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c swig/sphinxbase/ad.i

     unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
      error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1

 ----------------------------------------
 Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
 Running setup.py clean for pocketsphinx
 Failed to build pocketsphinx
 Installing collected packages: pocketsphinx
 Running setup.py install for pocketsphinx ... error
 Complete output from command /home/geek/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c  
 "import    
 setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-k634wg4p/pocketsphinx  
 /setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', 
 open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',  
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
/tmp/pip-q7w8xgtz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-  
managed --compile:
running install
running build_ext
building 'sphinxbase._ad' extension
swigging swig/sphinxbase/ad.i to swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c
swig -python -modern -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include
/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig  
 -outdir sphinxbase -o swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c swig/sphinxbase/ad.i
 unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: **Google Colab** users might want to look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54124548/5320982) answer. Also windows users do see check the link for further requirements of installing `pocketsphinx`.

Answer (score 13):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install swig
```

It installs swig, which is one of the requirements of pocketsphinx.

Comment: [How to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Add more details to justify your answer.

Comment: OP specifies that his OS is Win 10, apt-get does not seem to be a way to go

Answer (score 5):

If you are on **MacOSX** then, try this command.

```
brew install swig
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have Swig installed?
I had this same problem, and saw on [the PocketSphinx index at PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pocketsphinx#install-requirements) that one of the requirements is Swig, which can be downloaded at http://www.swig.org/download.html (hosted at SourceForge) and installed from source using the `./configure && make && make install` combo.
I then proceeded to install PocketSphinx from source, but it seems the problem was the same, so you could try to use pip still.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pocketsphinx
```

Comment: Swig missing seems to be the issue here.