# Couldn't install textract in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, text-extraction

I couldn't install `textract` in google colab, error message showing as below.

some people suggest to use `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev` but how to do `sudo...` in google colab?

=== error message ==========================================================

> Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx   Running setup.py clean for
>   pocketsphinx Failed to build pocketsphinx Installing collected
>   packages: pocketsphinx   Running setup.py install for pocketsphinx ...
>   error
>       Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-03c_ysbm/pocketsphinx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-record-6n9ewg9i/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build_ext
>       building 'sphinxbase._sphinxbase' extension
>       swigging deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i to deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
>       swig -python -modern -threads -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
>   deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
>       unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
>       error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1

===========================================================================
Thank you,
Ling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope you can't use `sudo` because you don't get `root` access for colab.

The problem is that you don't just need `libasound2-dev` but a whole host of packages. Check debian requirements in https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Also in order to build `sphinx` (a requirement for `textract`) you need `libpulse-dev`. So here is the updated command list.

```
!apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev antiword unrtf poppler-utils \
     pstotext tesseract-ocr \
     flac ffmpeg lame libmad0 libsox-fmt-mp3 sox libjpeg-dev swig libasound2-dev libpulse-dev
!pip install git+https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract
```

Comment: I SO wanted to upvote this answer...  can you help with  exceptions related to: Building wheel for pocketsphinx (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx   ?

Answer (score 2):

In google colab  Bash commands run by prefixing the command with ‘!’.

Example:

```
!apt update
!apt-get install libasound2-dev
```